# Count current employees

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to count my employees. in our system we have ids for employees and we can see if an employee is no longer with us from a end date column.

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Employee[SK_Employee]),
    FILTER(
        Employee,
        Employee[AnsatDato_DateInt] <= NOW()
    ),
    FILTER(
        Employee,
        OR(
            Employee[FratrDato_DateInt]>NOW(),
            ISBLANK(Employee[FratrDato_DateInt])
        )
    )
)
```

I tried this code but it did not work. I have a date table with date, months, years etc, but day only allow my to use the `now()` function not my date table which is in another table than the employee table.

kind regards Mathies

Comment: Hello Mathies, are you able to share the data model and a small sample of the data? 
My first concern is about having a unique date key in each table (Employee and Date tables). Your date table must be a date list with unique rows while you may have that date repeating in the employee table (1 to n relationship).

Comment: okay. i justed checked the data model and saw their is no direct connection. if i make the direct connection when i would be able to apply dates[date] instead of now()

Comment: Correct, when you get both connected with a 1 to n relationship you should be able to change NOW() for the date key. The DAX function NOW() returns datetime (Date with time). If you are comparing to a date column you might aswell use TODAY().